# How to get void print functions (that are within classes) printed to a text file

Tags: c++, class, void

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person                     //class Person
{
    public:                             //declare variables in the Person class
        string lastName, firstName, address, city, state, zip, phone;
        Person();

        void printPerson()                              //function used to print out the content inside this class
        {
            cout << firstName << " ";
            cout << lastName << endl;
            cout << address << ", ";
            cout << city << ", ";
            cout << state << " ";
            cout << zip << endl;
            cout << "Phone Number: " << phone << endl;
        }

};

class Customer : public Person {                    //declare class Customer; Customer is a derived class of Person
    public:
        int customerNumber;                       //declare variables 
        bool mailingList;
        string comments;
        Customer();

        void printCustomer()                     //function used to print the content in the Customer class as well as the Person class
        {

            printPerson();         

            cout << "Customer Number: " << customerNumber << endl;

            if (mailingList == true)
            {
                cout << "Mailing List: True" << endl;
            }
            if (mailingList == false)
            {
                cout << "Mailing List: False" << endl;
            }

            cout << "Comments: " << comments << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("testOutput.txt", ios::out);

    PreferredCustomer Igottaquestion;                                 //create an instance for PreferredCustomer
    Igottaquestion.lastName = "Igottaquestion";
    Igottaquestion.firstName = "Ed";
    Igottaquestion.address = "4901 Evergreen";
    Igottaquestion.city = "Dearborn";
    Igottaquestion.state = "MI";
    Igottaquestion.zip = "48126";
    Igottaquestion.phone = "313-436-9145";
    Igottaquestion.customerNumber = 1;    
    Igottaquestion.mailingList = true;
    Igottaquestion.comments = "class quentioner";
    Igottaquestion.printPreferredCustomer();


    Customer Kool;                                   //create an instance for Customer
    Kool.lastName = "Kool";
    Kool.firstName = "James";
    Kool.address = "1313 Colin Blvd";
    Kool.city = "Dearborn Heights";
    Kool.state = "MI";
    Kool.zip = "48127";
    Kool.phone = "313-836-9168";
    Kool.customerNumber = 3;
    Kool.mailingList = false;
    Kool.comments = "Class Answerer";
    Kool.printCustomer();

    cout << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, not only to the screen, I also need to print/output the result to a text file.

Normally, I can just do something like this:

ofstream outfile;

outfile.open("testOutput.txt", ios::out);

outfile << firstName << " ";

But, in this case, how can I get void print functions (that are embedded in classes) printed into a text file?

Comment: Can you edit the functions? Unless you are allowed to change the functions I don't see there's much you can do.

Comment: Based on the hw instruction, yes, I am allowed to edit the functions. I tried to edit the functions too, but I think opening the output file in every void print function simply re-writes the file over and over, and eventually, only the last function that got called will get printed to the file.

Comment: If the program prints the correct output, why don’t you use a simple utility called tee (on the command line, without modifying your program) or redirect the output?

Comment: Hint: C++ uses a `std::ostream&` to format data as text and send it ... somewhere. `std::cout` is one example; it sends the text to "standard output", which may connect to a terminal or screen. An object of type `std::ofstream` is another example; it sends the text to a file you told it to open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, just pass the place you want the output to go as a parameter to your functions. Like this

```
   void printPerson(std::ostream& out) // out is the destination we are writing to
    {
        out << firstName << " ";
        out << lastName << endl;
        out << address << ", ";
        out << city << ", ";
        out << state << " ";
        out << zip << endl;
        out << "Phone Number: " << phone << endl;
    }
```

Same change for `printCustomer` etc.

Then you use the functions like this

```
  ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("testOutput.txt", ios::out);

  Customer Kool;
  ...
  Kool.printCustomer(outFile); // write the customer to outfile
  outFile << endl;

  Person Aplus;
  ...
  Aplus.printPerson(outFile); // write the person to outfile
```

Comment: And I'd point out part of the point of this is, if you do `Kool.printCustomer(std::cout);` you still have the original behavior.

Comment: Yes, `std::ostream&` is compatible with any output stream, including file streams and `std::cout`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I never tried to do something like this before, so this might be a stupid question, but what should I put in the () of embedded print functions. I just edited my code in my question, if you copy and paste my code again, line 47 and line 105 are where I have problems. I tried to put "out" inside, but I get an empty text file when I run the program

Comment: If i put "std::ostream& out" inside these parentheses, I will get red underlines...and "out" is the only thing I can think of that I can put there and won't give me red underlines, but then I will get an empty txt file

Comment: @EmmaG Look again at what I wrote, you didn't copy it correctly.

Comment: @EmmaG Your version is still printing to `cout`, you need to change that to `out`.

Comment: @EmmaG And yes, `out` is what you should put in those parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You should overload << operator for your class,
this link will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019